# Why does my data gets saved only when i use app.get?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this node JS function to save a user on the Mongodb database

```
app.post("/user", async(req, res)=>{
const user = new User ({id: '8451845', name: "Jerry", lastname: "Tom", email: 
"TomJErry@gmail.com", pass: "123456789"});
try {
    await user.save();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
})
```

And when i navigate to "http://localhost:3001/user" it tells me cannot Get /user, but when i use app.get instead of app.post the user gets saved perfectly on the database, so why does the app.get save the data, i thought the POST method is the one responsible for creating

Comment: When you navigate to a URL, your browser performs a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: Ahh so the post only works when i send data from the frontend to save it?

Comment: The post route only works for POST requests, which are typically executed when you submit a form on a web page _or_ if you run Javascript code in the browser that explicitly performs such a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to lookup how HTTP works. When visiting a page in a browser, the browser sends a `GET` request to the webserver. `POST`, `PUT` etc requests are made in the code. `app.post` allows the webserver to listen to a `POST` request.